# PHP Thread Safe end 2012?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mpm-worker

Considering this question and answer

[List of PHP modules that are thread safe](https://serverfault.com/questions/157117/list-of-php-modules-that-are-thread-safe/419255#419255)
and
[Is PHP Thread Safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681081/is-php-thread-safe)

My question is, is PHP thread safe in 2012?

Comment: This might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/415075/worker-mpm-and-php

Comment: Afaik no, but you can try to use fpm. Details here : [http://serverfault.com/questions/415075/worker-mpm-and-php][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/415075/worker-mpm-and-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP [can be thread-safe](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.obtaining.php#faq.obtaining.optional) if you don't use non-thread-safe extensions. See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/thread_safety.html) for information on thread safety and checking that *your* PHP variant is thread safe for use with Apache. And have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500603/to-use-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-php) if you need help choosing between thread-safe or non-thread-safe editions of PHP: it depends on the Apache worker and how it handles requests (in terms of threads, processes, etc.).

Comment: thanks , at last i hope apache.org is up to date , so the answer is still "maybe"